# Autohotkey complete mapping of arrows

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I have this code so far using autohotkey (.ahk)

```
!k::SendInput,{UP}
!j::SendInput,{LEFT}
!æ::SendInput,{RIGHT}
!l::SendInput,{DOWN}
```

which correctly maps my arrow keys to j,k,l,æ accordingly. (æ is the ; key button on english keyboards)

This works like a charm except for the fact that I can't hold "ctrl+alt+j" for intance, to go to next word to the left as I do if I'm using "ctrl+arrowKeyLeft".

I need this to work with shift as well, to highlight the letters to the left. 
What happens now is simply nothing so I guess I'm supposed to tell the script that it should highlight text on "shift+alt+(j,k,l,æ)" somehow but I haven't been able to find a way to do this just yet.
Any help, likes or suggestions on how to do this is very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure of a good straightforward answer other than duplicating those lines with ctrl and shift added. Normally what you describe is undesirable - most people want ctrl+shift+Q to do something different than ctrl+(shift+Q) or shift+(ctrl+Q).

Comment: @NextInLine so something like:

^!j::SendInput,{CTRL+LEFT}

I guess?

Comment: Something like that. I can't get to AutoHotKey's site right now to check their docs.

Answer (score 0):

Following the line of thought in @NextInLine's comment, something like the below could be a starting point, but it seems that there's some funny business going on with Windows and these key combinations, so the current script is acting like a whole line selection instead of per-word. Perhaps testing on your system will result in different behavior.

Basically the script does as follows:

1. Check that the key state of Ctrl and Alt is True (pressed down).
2. If true, Loop the included code 20 times
3. Inside Loop, wait for j to be pressed for 2 seconds. If pressed, perform {Alt up}{Ctrl down}{Shift down}{LEFT}
4. Break loop if no j key is detected.

The code:

```
 ^!j::
 {
      if (GetKeyState("Ctrl", "P")) AND (GetKeyState("Alt", "P"))
        { 
        Loop, 20
        {
        KeyWait, j, D T2
        if (GetKeyState("j", "P"))
          {
          SendInput, {Alt up}{Ctrl down}{Shift down}{LEFT}
          }
        else
        {
          break
        }
        }
      SendInput, {Ctrl up}{Shift up}
      return
        }
    }
```